# Persistence of RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Consider the following code.

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("...").persist()
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_.length).persist()
val cnt = rdd2.count()
val rdd3 = rdd1.map(_.split(" ")).persist()
```

After `rdd2.count()` is called, is `rdd1` persisted? Or is `rdd1` persisted only if an action is called on it?

Comment: May be an idea to get the Action, Transformation paradigm correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rdd1` is persisted during `rdd2.count` action.
you can check spark ui so better understand the DAG